# Undefined method error for displaying in JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm writing a simple Ruby API for a to-do list.  Here is what I have so far:

API CONTROLLER:

```
 class ApiController < ApplicationController
   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

   private

   def authenticated?
     authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic {|username, password| User.where( username: username, password: password).present? }
   end

 end
```

API/USERS_CONTROLLER:

```
 class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticated?

  def index
   users = User.all
   render json: users, each_serializer: UserSerializer
  end

 end
```

ROUTES:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
 resources :users
end

resources :welcome, only: [:index]

root 'welcome#index'
end
```

When I try to navigate to the `api_users_path`, it brings up the error:

```
undefined method `authenticated?' for # Api::UsersController:0x007f36a3f779f8
```

I'm sure there is something simple I am missing, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Consider SO questions to be entries in a reference book of how to fix common programming problems. In reference books we don't use salutations ("hi!") or valedictions ("thanks!") or signatures ("Fred"). In other words, SO isn't a bulletin board or chat, it's a Q&A, where we value accuracy, and being succinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `authenticated?` method available to your `Api::UsersController`, change `private` to `protected` in `application_controller.rb`:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
   skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

   protected

   def authenticated?
     authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic {|username, password| User.where( username: username, password: password).present? }
   end

 end
```

Changing to `protected` will make that method available to `ApplicationController` and all of it's sub-classes. If it's set to `private` that method will only be available to `ApplicationController` itself.

You should also make sure that `Api::UsersController` inherits from `ApiController`:

```
class Api::UsersController < ApiController
...
end
```

Comment: Like I said before. :)

Answer (score 1):

The method `authenticated?` is defined on `ApiController`. `Api::UsersController` does not have access to this method. To use it on all your controllers you can define this method on `ApplicationController` as protected.